# Flat Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Is it true that a Riemannian manifold is flat, if and only if a coordinate transformation $f$ exists, such that the geodesics after transformation is in linear form $\mathbf{y}_t=\mathbf{a}t+\mathbf{y}_0$, where $\mathbf{y}=f(\mathbf{x})$ are the transformed coordinates?

Comment: It should be true (though you seem to be implicitly using a big coordinate chart to write the geodesics in). What have you tried to prove it? Have you looked at the holonomy group?